# Is $f:G\to G$ onto when $V(G)=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 |y\geq 0\}$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $X=\bigl\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\colon y\geq 0 \bigr\}$ be the vertex set of a graph $G$ in which $(x_1,y_1)\sim (x_2,y_2)$ if and only if both $|x_1-x_2|\le1$ and $|y_1-y_2|\le1$. Let $f\colon G\to G$ be a continuous map, that is, $(x_1,y_1)\sim (x_2,y_2)$ implies $f(x_1,y_1)\sim f(x_2,y_2)$. If $f(x,0)=(x,0)$, must $f$ necessarily be onto?

Comment: Mahtab, I believe I've reworded your question in a way that's easier to understand. Can you make sure that I've preserved the content of the question?

Comment: @GregMartin Sure, you do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

No, the function $f_1 : (x, y) \to (x, 0)$ works and is not onto. However, that relies on considering $(x, y)$ to be adjacent to itself. If you don't want that, $f_2 : (x, y) \to (x, y \mod 2)$ works.

$f_1$ and $f_2$ both satisfy the $f(x, 0) = (x, 0)$ condition so it remains to show that they're continuous.

It is hopefully clear that $f_1$ is continuous since adjacent vertices either end up in the same place or right beside each other.

$f_2$ is also continuous. The $x$ values stay the same after the mapping and there are only two output values for $y$ so you still have $|y_1 - y_2| \leq 1$. Two adjacent vertices also cannot end up in the same place since that would require $y_1  \equiv y_2 \mod 2$ which requires $|y_1 - y_2| \geq 2$.

Comment: I really appreciate your nice answer. Thanks very much for your help.